# Can custom properties be allowed to go to infinity?

Tags: objects, properties

Is it possible to allow a custom property value to go as high or low as needed?

In other words, is it possible to make a custom property without clamping it with a min and a max?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender does not accept infinity as min or max value for a custom property directly, only with a trick. Usualy you can get infinity (of a float) by typing `float("inf")` and negative infinity with `float("-inf")`. This works in skripts and the python console, but number-fields in Blender do not accept these values (although they can evaluate the expression, try `float("2.3")` for example).

What you can do instead is setting the min and max values to the smallest / largest possible number. I don't know a way to get these values in a number-field directly, but you can get them from the python console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Note that `sys.float_info.min` will NOT give you the smallest negative value, but the value closest to zero that a floating point number in python can represent. To get the smallest possible negative number just put a minus in front of the max value.
If you copy and paste this value into the number field, Blender will show `inf` as the value. This is how you get infinity.
[image]

If you click on the number field Blender will however still show a number with 308 digits, so I do not know how the numbers are handeled internally.

Comment: I'm guessing it's still limited at some point, but close enough to infinity for me :)

Answer (score 9):

Going off [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/11041/12761) answer, you can just input `1e39` to get `inf`, since Blender will clip it off to `float_info.max`.  Likewise, you can use `-1e39` to get `-inf`.  (If those don't get you `inf` values, just raise the exponent after the `e` until they do.)